# Python: Error = Class 'Foo' has no 'bar' member?

Tags: python, class, variables, printing, format

I am receiving an error:

AttributeError: type object 'Shop' has no attribute 'inventory'

my class is set:

```
class Shop(object):
    def __init__(self, name, inventory, margin, profit):
        self.name = name 
        self.inventory = inventory
        self.margin = margin
        self.profit = profit


# Initial inventory including 2 of each 6 models available
inventory = 12
# Markup of 20% on all sales
margin = .2
# Revenue minus cost after sale
for bike in bikes.values():
    profit = bike.cost * margin
```

and I want to print inventory:

```
print "Mike's Bikes has {} bikes in stock.".format(Shop.inventory)
```

but keep getting the same error. I can make it work with:

```
print "Mike's Bikes has %d bikes in stock." % (inventory)
```

but am trying to make the switch to .format()

Comment: Your **class** has no such attribute; you never created an instance of the class.

Comment: self.inventory = inventory?

Comment: The `__init__` method *only* runs if there is an actual `self`, an instance, created. You need to call the class to create an instance.

Comment: So add Shop() in the open code to instantiate it?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You never created an *instance* of the class, so the `Shop.__init__()` method was never run either.

Your *class* doesn't have such an attribute; the only attribute you defined for your `Shop` class is the `__init__` method itself.

Create an instance of the class, then look for the attribute on that instance:

```
# Initial inventory including 2 of each 6 models available
inventory = 12
# Markup of 20% on all sales
margin = .2
# Revenue minus cost after sale
for bike in bikes.values():
    profit = bike.cost * margin

bikeshop = Shop("Mike's Bikes", inventory, margin, profit)
print "Mike's Bikes has {} bikes in stock.".format(bikeshop.inventory)
```

In creating the instance with `Shop(....)`, Python created the instance and called the `__init__` method on that instance. As a result, the `inventory` attribute was added to the instance, and you can then access it via `bikeshop.inventory`.